# Vertically center text in text field in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm creating a login screen with fields for username and password, but the text always seems a little bit off to the top(see image).

[Image of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfRt3.png)

[How it should look (did with Photoshop)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJQqT.png)

How can i fix this?

Here is code for the TextFormField:

```
new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    child: new TextFormField(
                      maxLines: 1,
                      controller: controller,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter username.';
                        }
                      },
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Username',
                          suffixIcon: new IconButton(
                            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                            icon: new Container(
                                width: 36.0, child: new Icon(Icons.clear)),
                            onPressed: () {
                              controller.clear();
                            },
                            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                          prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.account_circle)),
                    ),
                  ),
```

And here is my general theme code, if that helps^^

```
new ThemeData(
    fontFamily: 'Product Sans',
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    buttonColor: Colors.green[300],
    accentColor: Colors.green[300],
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
    canvasColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
    textSelectionColor: new Color.fromRGBO(81, 107, 84, 0.8),
    bottomAppBarColor: Colors.blueGrey[800],
    primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
    indicatorColor: Colors.green[300],
    cardColor: Colors.white,
    highlightColor: Colors.green[300],
    errorColor: Colors.red[400],
    textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.green[300],
    splashColor: Colors.white10,
    buttonTheme: new ButtonThemeData(
        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(22.0))),
    inputDecorationTheme: new InputDecorationTheme(
        contentPadding:
            new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
            gapPadding: 3.0,
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(22.0))),
  ),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm having trouble reproducing this error using the ThemeData and limited code provided.  Please post the entire build() function.  [Here's what I'm seeing with this code and version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wckFG.png).

```
flutter --version

Flutter 0.4.4 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f9bb4289e9 (3 weeks ago) • 2018-05-11 21:44:54 -0700
Engine • revision 06afdfe54e
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58
```

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Product Sans',
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        buttonColor: Colors.green[300],
        accentColor: Colors.green[300],
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        canvasColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        textSelectionColor: new Color.fromRGBO(81, 107, 84, 0.8),
        bottomAppBarColor: Colors.blueGrey[800],
        primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        indicatorColor: Colors.green[300],
        cardColor: Colors.white,
        highlightColor: Colors.green[300],
        errorColor: Colors.red[400],
        textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.green[300],
        splashColor: Colors.white10,
        buttonTheme: new ButtonThemeData(
            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(22.0))),
        inputDecorationTheme: new InputDecorationTheme(
            contentPadding:
                new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                gapPadding: 3.0,
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(22.0))),
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        child: new TextFormField(
          maxLines: 1,
          controller: controller,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please enter username.';
            }
          },
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Username',
              suffixIcon: new IconButton(
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                icon: new Container(width: 36.0, child: new Icon(Icons.clear)),
                onPressed: () {
                  controller.clear();
                },
                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.account_circle)),
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the error is the font. You don't have the Product Sans font in your pubspec.yaml probably... I changed to Roboto and the problem is gone... Guess it's a font bug, not a flutter bug.

Comment: I managed to center text by replacing "prefixIcon" with "icon".

Answer (score 77):

You can try with **contentPadding** (.all or .only)

```
TextFormField(
...
decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
...
)
```

before
[image]

after[image]

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer because it really works and allows to use any font instead of just using robotic. Thanks!

Comment: This actually worked. But can someone explain why this works? I can't wrap my head around how 10.0 padding is centering the text in this input?

Comment: this will make a problem with other screens having different sizes

Comment: @Konstantin If you look at the documentation, there's a bunch of different content padding variations based on properties like `isOutline`, `isDense`, etc. Explicitly setting the content padding to be an even value all around puts your text in the center nicely.

Comment: @Caleb Lindsey, please, look at the date of question next time. It was asked 3 years ago. It's not relevant already

Answer (score 43):

**textAlignVertical.center** work for me.

example:

```
TextFormField(
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
  ...
)
```

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: How center is not the default value is mind boggling.

Comment: I was not logged in at stackoverflow but this answer needs an upvote.

Answer (score 41):

If you have a prefixIcon, setting isCollapsed to true is the trick.

```
TextField(
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(...),
    isCollapsed: true,
  ),
),
```

Comment: isCollapsed: true, is that's what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: for me ```textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,``` and   `isCollapsed: true,`  needed to work.

Comment: Nice, thank you! Vertical centering didn't work until adding `isCollapsed`

Answer (score 10):

`textAlign: TextAlign.center` is working if you use `isCollapsed: true` as well
here is an example:

```
Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.88 * 0.6,
        height: 40.0,
        color: Colors.amber,
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 18.0),
        child: TextField(
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
            obscureText: false,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              isCollapsed: true,
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: darkbrown),
              ),
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: darkbrown),
              ),
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: darkbrown),
              ),
              labelStyle: GoogleFonts.roboto(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
              hintText: "Hint text",
              hintStyle: GoogleFonts.roboto(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            )),
      ),
```

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyVHS.png)

Answer (score 4):

This helped me for vertical centering:

```
 TextField(
    ...
           decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                ...
           )
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm frustrated to see those answers, and none of them work for me until i do something silly like putting minus padding

```
InputDecoration(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: -5.0),
```

and no kidding, it works.

[image: Minus padding]

Comment: This worked for me as well. I had set expands to true and the text was displaced slightly to the top

Answer (score 4):

Specifying **suffixIcon/prefixIcon** is more suitable than suffix/prefix arguments (when using icons!). Sometimes, **suffix/prefix properties of a TextField instance, makes the widget's height a bit distorted** which is mostly undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I used both isCollapsed (set through decoration) to true and textAlignVertical to center is an appropriate solution for this problem instead of using contentPadding. Here is my code:

```
TextFormField(
      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
      maxLines: 1,
      style: Get.textTheme.bodyText1?.apply(
                fontSizeFactor: 1.5,
             ),
             decoration: InputDecoration(
             isCollapsed: true,
             prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
             border: InputBorder.none,
             floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
             label: Text(
                 'Search',
                 style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 20,
                 ),
             ),
             fillColor: AppColors.primary,
          ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextField(
 textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,),)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `suffix` instead of `suffixIcon` or wrap `TextField` with `Center`. This is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

if your textfield has maxlines  you can do it by set height of hint style according maxlines
like :if maxlines:5, you can set height:4

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33474717)

Answer (score -6):

*textfield input set vertically and horizontally center,*

```
textAlign: TextAlign.center
```

Comment: `TextAlign.center` make it center both horizontally and vertically. 
The question is only asking how to do it vertically.